# If () statement or while () loop in R

Tags: r, loops, if-statement, while-loop

```
x=matrix(0)
test <- vector(mode="numeric", length=196)
for(i in 1:196){
    x=c[c(1:(200+i*50)),]
    ts=BiCopGofTest(x[,1], x[,2], 1, par =  0.6 ,method="white",max.df = 30, B = 0, obj = NULL)
    test[i]=ts$statistic}
plot(test, type='l')
```

I have the matrix c which has 10,000 rows and 2 columns. I took the first 200 rows of matrix c and I calculated the value of the test. Each time I was increasing the number of rows by 50 and I was calculating the test. This is what is written in the code above.

What I want to do now is the following. I want to repeat the same process but when the test is greater than 7.81 I want to stop and return the array x. I want to use the array later so it's important to store it. Should I use an IF statement or a WHILE loop? Any help will be highly appreciated.

Comment: `if (ts$statistic > 7.81) break` should do what you want. `break` tells R to exit the for loop. You could make a similar construction with a while loop, that is just a matter of preference.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that by doing

```
x=c[c(1:(200+i*50)),]
```

in your loop, you are overwriting x, and you lose the original matrix. Also, your subset statement is not really correct. You should create a new variable which holds the subset of rows in your loop. You might do something like:

```
x=matrix(runif(10000*2,0,1),10000,2)
test <- vector(mode="numeric", length=196)

i=0

while(max(test)<7.81 & 200+i*50<=nrow(x)  )
{
     y = x[seq(1,200+i*50),] # y contains the first 200+i*50 rows of x
     ts= runif(1,1,7.9) # random test statistic, enter yours here.
     test[i]= sum(ts)
     i=i+1
}
plot(test, type='l')
```

This will continue your loop until either:

- there are no more rows in x
- the test statistic is greater than 7.81

Note that I do not have the package that includes `BiCopGofTest`, so I just used runif as my test statistic ;)

Hope this helps!

Comment: I have a question on what you wrote. You did this step x=matrix(runif(10000*2,0,1),10000,2) only because you wanted to create an array x with 10000 rows and 2 columns? Should I just replace x with my array c?

Comment: Yes, I just created some random sample data to test my script. Please note that c is not a really good name for a variable, since c is also used to construct a vector.

Comment: I just noticed a mistake that I did when I stated my question. My original array is the c which has 10,000 rows and 2 columns. Then I created the matrix x in order to access the different elements of c as described above.

Comment: I have a question regarding the while statement, i.e. while(max(test)<7.81 & 200+i*50<=nrow(x) ). You told me that this will continue looping until there are no more rows in x and until the test statistic is greater than 7.81. Given that I would like to stop until the test statistic is greater than 7.81 shouldn't I put OR instead of AND? I want to learn as well that's why I'm asking you to clarify this.

Comment: It will continue while both of them are `TRUE`, I added the word 'either' to my answer to clarify. If one of them stops being `TRUE` (i.e. you have looped through all rows, or a high enough test statistic was found), the loop will stop. because `TRUE & FALSE` returns `FALSE`. So the while condition no longer holds, and the while-loop will stop. If you use OR, it will continue looping until both of them are FALSE, since `TRUE | FALSE` returns `FALSE`. I hope this is a clear explanation. If you find my answer helpful, could you please accept or upvote it? Thanks!

Comment: That was very helpful thanks. I wanted to take the above test further. Please look at my original post for the second point.

Comment: Hi Gina, no problem at all. Changing your question after an answer has been given is quite confusing. If you have a follow-up question, please post that as a new one.